Overriding default subscript/superscripts with the tensor package
I wonder if it is possible to override the default sub/superscript commands with the ones coming from the tensor* package. So I would like TeX to read d^*_E as \tensor*{d}{^*_E}.
The reason why I am asking is that it seems to me that the default sub/superscripts seem to have different alignments depending on whether one has both a subscript and a superscript or just one of them.
For example,
d^*_E d_E + d_E d^*_E

renders as

and has a rather wacky looking alignment in the subscripts, whereas
\tensor*{d}{^*_E} \tensor*{d}{_E} + \tensor*{d}{_E} \tensor*{d}{^*_E}

renders as

which looks better.
Other suggestions for adjusting the alignment are of course welcome, I just found that the tensor package solves it, but I would prefer not to write out the full \tensor command every time.

d^{*}_{E}d^{}_E

@egreg Wonderfully simple!
